# jQuery Click event not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery menu plugin. initialy the plugin is operated with right click. (i know, weird) this plugin have a function for left click as well...but for some reason it dosent work.

The plugin's code as it is right now on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    var pieMenu = jQuery('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [
            { 
                path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/winamp.png",
                alt  : "Winamp",
                fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls';return false}
            },  { 
                path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/vlc.png",
                alt  : "VLC Media Player",
                fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls';return false}  
            },{ 
                path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/QuickTime.png",
                alt  : "Quick Time Player",
                fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.qtl';return false}
            },{ 
                path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/WMP.png",
                alt  : "Windows Media Player",
                fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.asx';return false}
            },{ 
                path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/popup.png",
                alt  : "נגן Popup",
                fn   : function(){$("#popupplay").click();return false}
            },{ 
                path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/iTunes.png",
                alt  : "iTunes",
                fn   : function(){alert('...בקרוב');return false}
            }],
        beforeMenuOpen: function(){
            jQuery('<div id="shadow"></div>').css(
            {
                'position':'fixed',
                'background-color':'#000000',
                'opacity': 0.6,
                'width':'100%',
                'height':'100%',
                'z-index' :999,
                'top':0,
                'left':0
            }).appendTo('body');
        },
        beforeMenuClose: function(){
            jQuery('#shadow').remove();
        }
    });

    $('#promo').click(function(){
    if($('#'+pieMenu.id).css('display') != 'block') //if jpie is not visible
    pieMenu.initMenu(200,200);

    })
});
</script>
```

as you can see..the last entry is the click function..the author gave this code for hover instead of click and pointed out that inorder to get left click... one just need to change .hover to .click  but its not working.

This is the click paramaters in the plugin's js file:

```
//click event
jQuery('#'+idCore).live({
    click: function() {
        if(closable)
            removeMenu();
    },
    contextmenu:function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
})
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: i dont fully know jsfiddle...can you explain more please?

Comment: See [the docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/) for http://jsfiddle.net. Select jQuery, add the plugin script as a resource, and place some HTML and JS snippets in the containers to build a fiddle that demonstanstrates your problem

Comment: Paste your html and CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/D9n38/ and give a link to the JS plugin file

Comment: it supposed to open the menu with left click...but its not

Comment: Getting TypeError: jQuery("#" + id).draggable is not a function
http://www.tranceil.fm/wp-content/themes/Tersus/js/jpie.js
Line 162 in [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/D9n38) and yours.
the ID is #pie0

Comment: PLEASE give the link to the original plugin page

Comment: @mplungjan you meen my website? www.tranceil.fm f you refer to the actual plugin -> http://codecanyon.net/item/jpie-jquery-circular-menu/2671812

Comment: check my website...hit right click on the headphones...its working there (with right click)

Comment: So if it works, then what is the question that you ask all over the web and here multiple times?

Comment: It only works with right click..and the reason im asking the whole web about it is the author of the plugin stated it works with left click with the above script. which it dosn't! and the author probably quit giving support..so i'm asking you guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

context: true,

to

context: false,

in the JS file

Comment: ok..now its working..:) only, how can i click again and remove the menu? with the right click if clicked anywhere again the menu closed..

Comment: It no longer closes? Perhaps you can add a document click that calls removeMenu if target is not the earphones